# x axis coords does not appear

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a tikzpicture like below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure*}[tp]
 \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
  \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={Speedup},
        xlabel = {Cores},
        bar width=7mm, y=4mm,
        symbolic x coords={8,16,32,64,128,256,512},
        xtick=data,
        %ytick={0,500,1000},
        %log basis y=10,
        x tick label style={},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
         legend cell align=left,
            legend style={
                    at={(1,1.05)},
                    anchor=south east,
                    column sep=1ex
            }
    ]

    \addplot [mark=diamond] coordinates{ %small
        (8,4.5) (16,6.2) (32,8.4) (64,9.6) 
    };
    \addplot [mark=o, color=blue] coordinates { %medium
       (64,16.8) (128,15.6) (256,16.8) (512,16.5)
    };
    \legend{Small, Medium}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}% pic 2
  \caption{\label{fig:speedup:small}}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{center}
```

The output result is presented in the image.

[image]

As it seems the x coordinates 128,256,512 does not appear in the diagram. Is anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xtick=data` only uses the data from the first `\addplot`.

Comment: Ok. You know how to fix this?

Comment: Ok. It fixed when I comment this line.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xtick=data` only takes the data from the first `\addplot` in the axis. In this case simply removing `xtick=data` fixes the problem, a more general solution is I think to replace it with `xtick distance=1`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        small, % added
        width=\linewidth, % added
        ylabel={Speedup},
        xlabel = {Cores},
        symbolic x coords={8,16,32,64,128,256,512},
        % not needed, but will force ticks at all data points
        % as symbolic coords have a unit distance of 1
        xtick distance=1, 
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                    at={(1,1.05)},
                    anchor=south east,
                    column sep=1ex,
                    font=\small
            }
    ]

    \addplot [mark=diamond] coordinates{ %small
        (8,4.5) (16,6.2) (32,8.4) (64,9.6) 
    };
    \addplot [mark=o, color=blue] coordinates { %medium
       (64,16.8) (128,15.6) (256,16.8) (512,16.5)
    };
    \legend{Small, Medium}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```